# How to pass a variable to model in laravel to create dynamic table name

Tags: laravel, variables, model

I am trying to create table name on run time based on the user id and user name. But, I am not able to do it. Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use App\User;


class Transaction extends Model
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $name = user::find($id)->name; 
    $table_name = 'tumble'.'__'.$name.'_'.$id; 
    protected $table = $table_name;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create tables using  [schema builder](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#creating-and-dropping-tables)

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use App\User;


class Transaction extends Model
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $name = user::find($id)->name; 
    $table_name = 'tumble'.'__'.$name.'_'.$id; 
    protected $table = $table_name;   
$this->createTable($tableName);
}

private function createTable($tableName)
{
Schema::create($tableName, function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    // set here you columns just like migration ...
});
}
```